# Open network folder in a .bat file

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

How do I open a network folder with a .bat file?
**explorer shell:NetworkPlacesFolder** works like wonders in CMD but once I try to implement a path (e.g. \\104pc01-01\c$\), it simply doesnt work and I can't find anything online.

I thought I could just do explorer \\ but that didn't work, so I tried using shell:NetworkPlacesFolder, pushd and other gimickry that still didn't work

Comment: Put the batch file on the desktop. I open network folders daily this way.

Comment: You can use `pushd \\server\share` to go to that folder (it automatically maps it to a free driveletter) then run `explorer .` to start explorer there, and at the end of your script, write `popd` to remove the driveletter again. Also, try renaming your .bat file to .cmd and try again. .bat uses old instructions, .cmd uses modern. sounds weird, but for this kind of thing, it may fix it.

Comment: Works for me : `explorer \\Computer\C$`.

Comment: @LPChip thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: Glad I could help. Was it the pushd method or using .cmd that fixed it for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
start \\whatever\your\network\path
```

in the `whatever.bat` file (this works for me running from both `PowerShell` and `cmd.exe`.

Do note: your network path must be full, e.g. in Explorer it might be shown as: `This PC > (\\whatever) (T:)` where `T:` is the drive letter, and You see some (e.g. `path` from the above example) folder(s) there, but that folder might not be right below `T:` in the directory structure since Windows allows mounting a network share/folder to a letter, thus You might have to figure out the whole path.

Comment: Note `start "title" file-or-command` - that "title" will make things hard at times.